# XML data extract based on specific node

Tags: php, xml, extract

I am strugling to extract some information from an xml file based on specific node from a XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <XMLResponse>
    <ResponseType>HotelListResponse</ResponseType> 
    <TotalNumber>2</TotalNumber> 
    <Hotels>
      <Hotel>
        <HotelCode>YYYYYY</HotelCode>
        <OldHotelId>X/XXXXXXXX</OldHotelId> 
        <DestinationId>XXXX</DestinationId> 
        <Destination>Name of city</Destination> 
        <Country>Name of country</Country> 
        <HotelName>Hotel Name</HotelName> 
        <StarRating>x</StarRating> 
        <HotelAddress>Hotel address</HotelAddress>
        <HotelPostalCode>Zip Code</HotelPostalCode>
        <HotelPhoneNumber>Hotel phone number</HotelPhoneNumber> 
        <HotelArea>Hotel area</HotelArea>
        <Chain>Hotel Chain</Chain> 
        <Coordinates>
          <Latitude>latitude</Latitude> 
          <Longitude>longitude</Longitude> 
        </Coordinates>
        <HotelImages>
          <ImageURL>URL1</ImageURL> 
          <ImageURL>URL2</ImageURL> 
          <ImageURL>URL3</ImageURL> 
        </HotelImages>
      </Hotel>
  </Hotels>
</XMLResponse>
```

I want to get(pull) the information from `<HotelName> </HotelName>` based on `<HotelCode>YYYYY</HotelCode>`
The "YYYYY" is echoed in my php file (`<?php echo  $hotel->hotelCode?><`)
I have tried and read all the examples that i have found but none of them helped me.

Any help would be much apreciated.

Comment: "all the examples"... What exactly have you tried and is not working? SO is not meant to write your code for you. Check the way to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry about that. I have read all the examples from http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_get.asp and

Comment: You are coding in PHP. Please read the examples and comments on the PHP reference site: http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple to do with [`xpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php).

#### Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load($file);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//Hotel[HotelCode = "YYYYYY"]/HotelName)');
```

#### Result:

```
Hotel Name
```

Comment: Thanks alot.$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('https://www.bookingassist.ro/test.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
echo $xpath->evaluate('string(//Hotel[HotelCode = "YYYYYY"]/HotelName)');